# Java agent - Protect -XX:+StartAttachListener

Tags: javaagents

I am trying to setup instrumentation for my Java process thru remote agent and hence running my Java process with -XX:+StartAttachListener. Once I enable this, it lets anybody from the remote machine to attach their java agent. Is there a way to protect this using credentials?